# "haltingproblem" Contradiction Proof

Tags: computation-theory, halting-problem

I recently came across the halting problem contradiction proof.
In the proof, we have to feed the Turing machine a copy of the program and a copy of the input to decide whether that program halts on the input. In the contradiction, why does it have to be the program as the program and the input? Sorry if it sounds confusing. I can simply feed the machine with a program and a random input and come to the same conclusion.

Can anyone tell me why? Is there a specific reason I didn't think of?

Answer (score 0):

First let me come back on the proof itself.

**HALT_TM is undecidable**

Assume that any machine has a description which takes the form of a string. Let `HALT_TM = {<M, w>| M is a TM and M halts on input w}`, and `A_TM = {<M,w>| M is a TM and accepts w}`. Here I assume that we know that `A_TM` is undecidable (the proof can be done by diagonalization and realizing that as there are more languages than Turing Machines, and as a given TM only decide one language, then some language are not decided).

Assume by contradiction that `HALT_TM` is decidable, meaning that we dispose of a decider `D` for this language. Then we would be able to build a machine `M` which decides `A_TM`. On input `<M', w>`, `M` does the following:

- Run `D` on input `<M',w>`
- If `D` reject, reject, otherwise run `M'` on `w` (until it halts, which we know because `D` did not reject!)
- If `M'` accepts, accept, if it rejects, reject.

There we see the contradiction with our assumption

**Universal Turing Machines**

Now the core of your question: you actually feed `M` any valid machine description `M'`, not necessarily `<M>` itself. Remember that a TM and "a program" are actually equivalent: See this nice [answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13669/what-is-the-difference-between-an-algorithm-a-language-and-a-problem) for more details. Quoting this same answer: "*A Turing Machine is the formal analogue of an algorithm*".
One power of Turing Machines is that they can be encoded as a string, allowing another Turing Machine (called an "[Universal Turing Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Turing_machine)") to execute them. Because the given machine is an algorithm, you see that you are actually feeding your "top-level" TM a program, and a input of your choice.